# Pointwise boundedness problem in functional calculus / holomorphic functions mapping to Banach spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, holomorphic-functions

I have encountered the following problem in a book I am reading introducing functional calculus.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be complex Banach spaces and let $T: \Omega \rightarrow L(X,Y)$ be a weakly continuous function, defined on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. Assume that $\overline{B_r(z_0)}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-z_0| \leq r \} \subset \Omega$.

Now I have the following question:

> How do I show that $\sup_{|z-z_0|=r} ||A(z)x||_Y < \infty$, i.e. that this family is pointwise bounded? I know that this must be using that weak continuity, since otherwise it would not be written there. But what is weak continuity and how do I show pointwise boundedness?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose weak continuity means continuity with respect to weak operator topology on $L(X, Y)$. That is, for every fixed $x\in X$ and every fixed $y^*\in Y^*$ the map 
$$
z \mapsto \langle A(z)(x), y^*\rangle 
$$
is continuous in $\Omega$.

Continuity implies boundedness on compact subsets of $\Omega$. The set $\{z:|z-z_0|=r\}$ is compact. Hence, for each $x, y^*$ as above there exists $M$ such that 
$$
|\langle A(z)(x), y^*\rangle|\le M,\quad \text{for all } \ |z-z_0|=r
\tag1 $$
Each $A(z)(x)$ is a linear functional on $Y^*$. The inequality (1) says this family of functionals is pointwise bounded. By the Uniform Boundedness Principle it is norm-bounded: that is,  there exists $M'$ such that 
$$
\| A(z)(x) \| \le M',\quad \text{for all } \ |z-z_0|=r
\tag2 $$
as claimed.